# Joomla 2.5 Session LifeTime

Tags: php, database, session, joomla

I have problem with joomla 2.5 user session lifetime. I set lifetime on 5 min in configuration.php but it not works. What may the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Global Configuration > System there is an option for Session Lifetime. For 5 min the number there should just be '5', if not I suggest you change it there, rather than edit the configuration.php directly. Another idea would be to restart the server/application, to force joomla to load the settings.

Comment: If the other method didn't work, yes I would try restarting the web server if you are able to.